# How to disable auto-created string in new VS 2022?

Tags: visual-studio

VS 2022 has a new "feature": when I hit `enter` in a quoted string literal, it splits the string so that there's a new partial string, `+` outside the string, a newline, and the rest of the string on the next line.

... that is, hitting `enter` while the cursor is between the 'u' and first 'f' turns

```
var foo = "stuff";
```

into

```
var foo = "stu" +
"ff";
```

How do I disable this "feature" (specifically for C#, but applying to all languages would be preferable)?

Specifically: when I hit `enter`, I want a plain ol' newline. If that makes the code invalid, so be it: I can decide whether to remove the newline, use string concatenation, use a multi-line string literal, or whatever else may be needed to fix the code.

Comment: What would you want to have VS do instead? I find the feature quite useful if you have long string constants (such as detailed error messages).

Comment: @PMF: I want it to insert a newline, even if that means that the code is illegal.

Comment: @minnmass Are you looking for "Tools" menu -> "Options" -> "Text Editor" -> "C#" -> "Advanced" -> Under "Editor Help", "Split string literals on enter"?

Comment: @AndrewMorton: yes, that's exactly it! Or, at least, it does the thing. It was enabled in my instance of 2019, but apparently didn't "take", so it never did anything.